# ро-метод Полларда дискретного логарифмирования:

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь разобраться с этим алогритмом. Имеется код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

 const int n = 1018, N = n + 1;  /* N = 1019 -- prime     */
 const int alpha = 2;            /* generator             */
 const int beta = 5;             /* 2^{10} = 1024 = 5 (N) */

 void new_xab( int& x, int& a, int& b ) {
   switch( x%3 ) {
   case 0: x = x*x     % N;  a =  a*2  % n;  b =  b*2  % n;  break;
   case 1: x = x*alpha % N;  a = (a+1) % n;                  break;
   case 2: x = x*beta  % N;                  b = (b+1) % n;  break;
   }
 }

 int main(void) {
   int x=1, a=0, b=0;
   int X=x, A=a, B=b;
   for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i ) {
     new_xab( x, a, b );
     new_xab( X, A, B );
     new_xab( X, A, B );
     printf( "%3d  %4d %3d %3d  %4d %3d %3d\n", i, x, a, b, X, A, B );
     if( x == X ) break;
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Все хорошо работает над заданным примером(a=2,b=10,n=1019).Суть заключается в следующем: имеется уравнение a^y=b(mod n). Надо найти y. Программа работает до тех пор, пока х!=Х. Затем, чтобы получит наш y, надо (a-A/B-b). В нашем случае, получилось, что x=1010, а y=(681-301)/(416-378)=10. Ответ, правильный. Если поменять значения на (a=3,b=11,n=17), то уже считает не правильно. В чем проблема? Описание алгоритма тут:
[Поллард](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms)

Comment: Какие значения меняете, на что меняете, что перестаёт работать правильно? Это конечно хорошо, что вы привели код и название алгоритма, однако вывод программы в данном случае будет не лишним. Пока вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @Александр, учитывая вчерашний вопрос про Евклида, я так понимаю, уже понял, в чём заблуждался?

Comment: Да, спасибо разобрался

Comment: @Сашка, хорошим тоном было бы дать ответ на свой вопрос...